# attach string variable to document object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a variable called `current_slide` which contains a string called `"default"`

Now I have a object called `document.referencemap`:

How can I attach the `"default"` string from `current_slide` to the object `document.referencemap` so that I will get 
`document.referncemap.default` ?

What is the best way to attach a string to the object?

At the moment I am calling the object property manually like: 
`document.referncemap.default`.

Can anybody give me a hint so I can solve this issue?

My code looks like this

[image: My code]

Because the current slide is always changing i need to load the object from the value of current_slide.

Comment: do you need a value for the object or a new property? why do you have a property of `document`?

Comment: `document.referencemap.default = "default"` ?

Comment: `document.referencemap[current_slide]` = ... ?

Comment: the document.referncemap is a object. which contains multiple objects like default, default1, default2 etc. 

i can call the objects now when when when i write document.referncemap.default, document.referncemap.default1 etc. 

The situation is this i have the object.referencemap and want to call the object in the referncemap through the value of the variable i got in current_slide

Comment: i added a code sample may i would be clearer now

Comment: i allready have a property in document.referncemap.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
temp0 = document.referencemap[current_slide.slide];
```

Explanation:
There are two ways to get values from Javascript objects,

1. using property notation: `temp0 = document.referencemap.welcome;`
2. using dictionary notation: `temp0 = document.referencemap["welcome"];`

This will get the exact same item from the object. Note however that **2.** uses a **string** key. Because of that you can also use a variable that *contains* a string, in this case: `temp0 = document.referencemap[current_slide.slide];`

Answer (score 0):

use:

`document.referencemap[current_slide] = booBar`

make sure current_slide is of type string. Read the [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)
docs for more information.

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture of my code. May that would be more clearer. 

I want to replace the welcome (which i marked yellow) with the result of current_slide.slide

Comment: Than use `delete document.referencemap.welcome` and after that assign the new property with the bracket notation if I get you right what you want to achieve

Comment: No that not exactly what i wanted 

I wanted to Dynamically access object property using variable

I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable